# Where can I find the clipboard viewer in vista

Tags: windows-vista, clipboard

In XP I can run "clipbrd" or something and it will open a small program that contains the contents of the clipboard.

I would like to do this in Vista, but not really sure where it is or what it is called. I have googled around and most of the answers have been to "download it from the internet", "just ctrl+V and you will see it", or "it comes with microsoft office word as clip.exe"

Is there a vista equivalent of XP's "clipbrd" utility in one of the system folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vista there **isn't** the clipboard viewer, but you can still use a **workaround**.

[Free Clipboard Viewer](http://www.htwares.com/windows/system-utilities/clipboard-tools/free-clipboard-viewer/) is an userful utility to see the content of the clipboard.